# Using a prediction model designed with R in an Android app

Tags: android, r, android-studio, prediction

I have trained a *randomForest* model in R with a huge dataset that can predict whether a baby is going to have any possible allergies or not. My model in R is designed like this:

```
my.model <- randomForest(y=response, x=predictors)
```

When I test my model on the test dataset, I get a very high accuracy. Now I want to use such a model in an Android (or even iOS) app that allows users to provide data about their own babies and the app displays the prediction results. I searched different sources and haven't found any tips on how to do that.

Any suggestions on how to do this. Appreciate any help. 
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried writing a Shiny app to deploy to a browser on a phone? This has worked for me in the past, and although I only did a couple test apps (nothing in production), it seems to be a reasonable thing to consider. Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @mysteRious. The problem is that there are ready apps that want to incorporate my model into their apps.

Comment: You could use plumber (https://www.rplumber.io) to expose the model as a REST service. You would need a server to host the Webservice, though.